# Compactness of semigroups, boundary conditions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, semigroups-of-operators, dirichlet-forms

I have a question about compactness of semigroups and boundary conditions.

Let $\Omega$ be an **unbounded** domain of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with smooth boundary and $m(\Omega)=\infty$. Then we can define two bilinear forms (Dirichlet forms) on $L^{2}(\Omega)$.
\begin{align*}
&\mathcal{E}^{D}(f,g)=\int_{\Omega}(\nabla f, \nabla g)\,dx,\quad f,g \in H_{0}^1(\Omega), \\
&\mathcal{E}^{N}(f,g)=\int_{\Omega}(\nabla f, \nabla g)\,dx,\quad f,g \in H^1(\Omega), \\
\end{align*}
where $H_{0}^1(\Omega)$ and $H^1(\Omega)$ denote $(1,2)$-Sobolev space with Dirichlet boundary condition and $(1,2)$-Sobolev space with Neumann boundary condition, respectively. $\{T_t^D\}_{t>0}$ (resp. $\{T_t^{N}\}_{t>0}$) denotes the semigroup on $L^{2}(\Omega)$ associated with $(\mathcal{E}^D,H_0^1(\Omega))$ (resp. $(\mathcal{E}^N,H^1(\Omega))$). We say that $\{T_t^D\}_{t>0}$ (resp. $\{T_t^{N}\}_{t>0}$)
 is compact if $T_{t}^{D}$ (resp. $\{T_t^{N}\}_{t>0}$) is compact operator for every $t>0$.

**Question**

Do you know any examples of $\Omega$ such that $\{ T_{t}^D \}$ is compact and $\{T_{t}^N\}$ is not compact ?

Comment: Your question is equivalent of asking when the embedding of the Sobolev spaces in your question is compact in $L^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find examples in this paper:
http://math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/212.pdf